# In which occasions is renderRoot fired on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I am trying to optimise an application which has performance issues on drag and drop functionality. I am using react-dnd for that.

I have been able to filter out unnecessary re-renders which were clearly slowing the process down.

However, when I look at the flamechart, it seems to run renderRoot() 5-6 times. When reading about the subject, I understood that this is a part of the process everytime there is a change in state or props of any component. When I do other actions though, I can not always find the renderRoot() happening, and this puzzles me.

My question is, when and why does the renderRoot() happen?